# What happens to metals and ceramics under high hydrostatic pressure?

Tags: pressure, matter

What would happen to metals or ceramics (non-porous) when subjected to extremely high pressures (dozens of GPa) ?

I feel like the sample will deform elastically only. So a ceramic object (think carbides) wouldn't crack.

Typically, we assign a maximal compressive strength to metals and ceramics. After which, they undergo plastic deformation or fracture but these compressive strength values derive from experiments involving the pressing of a sample with an hydraulic press. So in these experiments, there is "space" without stress on the sides where the material could expand. But that isn't the case in an hydrostatic context where stress/pressure is applied evenly on all surfaces.

Also, in the case of ceramics, I feel like fracturing would create more volume which seems contradictory to me as the sample is being compressed.(in the sense that work should be done against the pressure if the sample gets more voluminous and that wouldn't minimise the energy)

If I am correct, you could have solid matter even at gigantic pressures. Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Your reasoning is correct; hydrostatic pressure can’t really damage uniform materials. It’s [deviatoric stress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_stress_tensor#Stress_deviator_tensor) (sort of a 3D version of shear, although it can contain non-shear components) that leads to permanent deformation and damage. All pressure can do is temporarily squeeze the constituent atoms closer together. (Hydrostatic stress changes sizes, and deviatoric stress changes shapes.)

An interesting graphical interpretation involves  the [von Mises yield criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mises_yield_criterion) for ductile materials. As long as the stress state remains inside the cylinder, only elastic deformation is predicted. Hydrostatic stress corresponds to the center axis of that cylinder.